# API Phpunit Test issue

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I'm having issue with testing of restful api using phpunit test. I have an endpoint like http://myserver-domain.com/get-user/1234?token=asdfiwerds, when try to run it thru postman or browser it working fine i see the results but when try to run it using phpunit the response is "No record found" here's the code of my test:

```
/**
 * @group userendpoint
 */
public function test_user_endpoint(){
    $response = $this->get('http://myserver-domain.com/get-user/1234');
    if($response->getStatusCode() !== 200){
        print json_decode($response->getContent())->msg;
    }

    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
    $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    $this->assertArrayHasKey('profile', $data);
}
```

this is the expected response ( i see this in browser and postman):

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        .... 
    }
}
```

It's kinda weird error for me, because it can get the record using browser and postman. Is there any wrong in my code. Please advise, thanks

Comment: do you get the statusCode 200 ?

Comment: yes, but no record details of the user. it failed in assertArrayHasKey(). but when running in browser and postman, details are complete

Comment: and what does $response->getContent() and $data return?

Comment: $reponse->getContent() is the json reponse from the api, but in my case the response from phpunit is just like { }, $data is convert it to array so that i can assertArrayHasKey() which is failed because the $reponse is blank

Answer (score 0):

Check if your header is set to application/json